# Getting runtime error in C in spoj toandfro classical

Tags: c, debugging, compilation, runtime-error, runtime-compilation

Here is the link to the problem.
http://www.spoj.com/problems/TOANDFRO/
 And here is the link to my code
http://ideone.com/w5wafl
On codepad,it says floating point exception. Here is link to codepad
http://codepad.org/FW9bKp5k (remove the space bw code--pad)
why is it giving runtime error. is it because of error in strings or array.
 I am putting the code here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int width_of_array, length_of_array, i,j , k;
    k = 0;
    char input_array[300], answer[300][300];

    scanf("%d", &width_of_array);
    scanf("%s", input_array);

    length_of_array = strlen(input_array) / width_of_array;
    for (i = 0 ; i < length_of_array ; i++)
     {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
         {  
            for ( j = 0 ; j < width_of_array ; j++)
              {
                answer[i][j] = input_array[k++];
              }
         }
        else
         {
            for (j = width_of_array - 1 ; j >= 0 ; j--)
              {
                answer[i][j] = input_array[k++];
              }
         }
    }
    for (j = 0 ; j < width_of_array ; j++)
     {
        for (i = 0 ; i < length_of_array ; i++)
         {
            printf("%c", answer[i][j]);
         }
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never check `scanf()`'s return value, the value of `width_of_array` might be `0` or anything, there is no way to know unless you confirm that `scanf()` returned `1`.

Comment: In any of your test you don't give any input and expect output . How is that going to give you correct result without behaving wired ?

Comment: @iharob Sorry.My fault. Feeling like an idiot now. am a bit new to competitive programming. Should have checked before.

Comment: Anyways, thanks a lot.it worked.

Comment: @ameyCU thanks, for explaining it. It works now.

Comment: http://www.kodemonk.com/toandfro-to-and-fro/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `length_of_array = strlen(input_array) / width_of_array;` will be a division by zero if the user inputs zero as the width of the array.  CodePad flags this as a floating point error, but at runtime it results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. It would have been another possiblity, but it was mentioned that values are greater than zero,so this was not the problem.Anyways, Thanks!!